# Residue Theory Limit

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having problems showing the part of the solution I have highlighted in green.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way: $z_0 := i \pi /2$ is a simple pole and the numerator is nonzero there, so we simply get the numerator evaluated at $z_0$ divided by the derivative of the denominator evaluated at $z_0$.

The other way:
You know the Taylor series of $\exp$. Now expand numerator and denominator as a series in $z - z_0$.

Comment: With the first method are you talking about using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Yeah, it is basically L'Hopital's rule applied to complex-differentiable functions. But what I just said is often taken as an alternative way of computing the residue (i.e. without explicitly multiplying by $z-z_0$ and taking the limit). It is important to remember that it only works for simple poles.

Comment: Even though with a pole of say order 2 would still satisfy the $"\frac{0}{0}"$ condition?